# What is the optimum application of petroleum jelly on a wound to help minimize scarring?

Tags: scar-tissue-scars, topical-cream-gel, wound-care, abrasion-cut-laceration

Looking at different sites online, I am having difficulty finding a clear, consistent information on the use of petroleum jelly to promote healing and minimize scarring.

What criteria should be used to decide when to use petroleum jelly on an abrasion rather than antibiotic ointment, or no ointment at all?

When using it, what is the optimal timing to apply it - straight away, after the scab has fully formed, or after the scab has fallen off?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE :-)  You said that *"the answers on the internet seem pretty divided."*  What answers have you seen and where?

Comment: I am altering the question to more closely meet new site standards and increase chances of being answered, while retaining the original intent.  Feel free to revert if disagree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/after-a-skin-biopsy-is-it-preferable-to-use-vaseline-polysporin-or-neosporin/11783#11783